# Replacing NULL by another value during a JOIN operation in HSQLDB

Tags: sql, database, hsqldb

When I run the following script (`q.sql`) using HSQLDB 2.2.5, the contents of `results.csv` becomes the following:

**results.csv**:

```
C1,C2
[null],e
a,b
```

**q.sql:**

```
DROP TABLE "PUBLIC"."TABLE1" IF EXISTS;

CREATE TABLE "PUBLIC"."TABLE1" (
  "C1" VARCHAR(10),
  "C2" VARCHAR(10),
  "C3" VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO "PUBLIC"."TABLE1" ("C1", "C2", "C3") VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c');
INSERT INTO "PUBLIC"."TABLE1" ("C1", "C2", "C3") VALUES ('d', 'e', 'f');

DROP TABLE "PUBLIC"."TABLE2" IF EXISTS;

CREATE TABLE "PUBLIC"."TABLE2" (
  "C1" VARCHAR(10),
  "C2" VARCHAR(10),
);

INSERT INTO "PUBLIC"."TABLE2" ("C1", "C2") VALUES ('a', 'b');
INSERT INTO "PUBLIC"."TABLE2" ("C1", "C2") VALUES ('u', 'v');

DROP TABLE "PUBLIC"."TABLE3" IF EXISTS;

CREATE TABLE "PUBLIC"."TABLE3" (
  "C1" VARCHAR(10),
  "C2" VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO "PUBLIC"."TABLE3" (
  "C1",
  "C2"
)
SELECT
(SELECT
"T2"."C1" AS "T2C1"
FROM "PUBLIC"."TABLE2" "T2"
WHERE "T2"."C1" = "T1"."C1") AS "T2C1",
"T1"."C2" AS "T1C2"
FROM "PUBLIC"."TABLE1" "T1"
ORDER BY "T2C1", "T1C2";

* *DSV_COL_DELIM=,
* *DSV_ROW_DELIM=\n
* *DSV_TARGET_FILE=results.csv

\x "PUBLIC"."TABLE3"
```

How can I change my script such that "`[null]`" gets replaced by "?" in the resulting CSV file?

Comment: so none of the proposed solutions meets your need?  I'm somewhat surprised since the link is directly from hSQLDB documentation.  Surely its one of the implementations not the functions themselves.

Answer (score 1):

depending on dbengine:

for hSQL... any of the 3 work according to: [hSQLDB.org](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/builtinfunctions-chapt.html)

coalesce (MOST)

NVL (oracle)

ifNull(mysql)
EDITED TO add ( ...(Oops I forgot!)

```
SELECT
coalesce((SELECT
"T2"."C1" AS "T2C1"
FROM "PUBLIC"."TABLE2" "T2"
WHERE "T2"."C1" = "T1"."C1"),'?') AS "T2C1", 
"T1"."C2" AS "T1C2"
FROM "PUBLIC"."TABLE1" "T1"
ORDER BY "T2C1", "T1C2";
```

Comment: I tried `COALESCE` and `IFNULL` but, they didn't work. HSQLDB complained about SELECT saying that it was an unknown object.

Comment: This is almost correct, but needs an extra open parens after coalesce `SELECT COALESCE((SELECT`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inserting the value from the table, use [case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) syntax on the insert to check if the value is null.

Something like this:

```
case when value = [null] then ? else variable end
```

Comment: The case statement would be equivalent to `COALESCE` and `COALESCE` didn't work. So, if you try the case statement you'll see that it doesn't work either.

Comment: Surely you meant to say `CASE WHEN value IS NULL THEN '?' ELSE value END`.  ("= NULL" is always false, a naked ? is a parameter marker, "[null]" is an artifact of output display not input syntax, and "value" and "variable" suggest different columns which is not what the OP wants.)